# Display different data in tableView according to which button clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview on the bottom of a view controller. I am trying to display different things on the tableview depending on which button was clicked. I have my different prototype cells and configuration methods for their data set up, however I cannot get the last bit. Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count = Int ()
    if podsButton.isSelected {
        count = pods.count
    } else if subscribedButton.isSelected {
        count = subscribers.count
    } else if subscribersButton.isSelected {
        count = subscribed.count
    }
    return count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell ()
    if podsButton.isSelected{
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileCell") as? ProfileTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell() }
        let pod = pods[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(pod: pod)
    } else if subscribedButton.isSelected {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FollowingCell") as? FollowingTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell() }
        let user = subscribed[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(user: user)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Right now the tableview displays nothing. The cell I am returning in cellForRow, is only the variable and not one of the conditional options that gets dequeued right? This is my issue. Also the first option (ProfileCell) should be the default. Thank you for any help.

UPDATE:

Now using my enum my code looks like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    if case .pods = displayState {
        count = pods.count
    } else if case .subscribed = displayState{
        count = subscribers.count
    } else if case .subscribers = displayState {
        count = subscribed.count
    }
    return count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if case .pods = displayState{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileCell") as! ProfileTableViewCell
        let pod = pods[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(pod: pod)
        return cell
    } else if case .subscribed = displayState {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FollowingCell") as! FollowingTableViewCell
        let user = subscribed[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(user: user)
        return cell
    } else if case .subscribers = displayState {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FollowingCell") as! FollowingTableViewCell
        let user = subscribers[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(user: user)
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

I am setting the displayStates in the button actions like so:

```
@IBAction func podsButtonClicked(_ sender: BottomBorderButton) {
    displayState = .pods
    podsButton.addBottomBorderWithColor(color: greenColor(), width: 3)
    subscribedButton.removeBottomBorder()
    subscribersButton.removeBottomBorder()
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

I think this is working , but I am now having a Parse query issue:

```
    // Query for the users that the user is subscribed to
    let subscribedQuery = Following.query()
    subscribedQuery?.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId as Any)
    subscribedQuery?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                self.subscribed.insert(object as! PFUser, at: 0)
            }
        }
    })
```

Error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Speakable.Following' (0x100552ec0) to 'PFUser' (0x100a12808).

UPDATE***

Fixed this with an includeKey but am now getting

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.'

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData` in your button actions?

Comment: @rmaddy I am not, let me try that. Right now I Was just adding an underline on the button. I was pretty sure that the cell I am returning though is not the cells that get dequeued , but the initial cell "let cell = UITableVIewCell"

Comment: You should remove the first `let cell =` line from your `cellForRowAt`. You should also remove the `guard` keyword and force-cast the result. And then add a `return cell` inside each block.

Comment: Downvoted question lol ? smh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot you should change in your code.

Make sure you select some initial button in `viewDidLoad`. Make sure you call `reloadData` in your button actions.

And you should refactor your `cellForRowAt` properly. In your current code, the `cell` variable of the `guard` is different from the `cell` variable before the first `if` so you actually always return the empty `UITableViewCell` instance you needlessly create.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if podsButton.isSelected{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileCell") as! ProfileTableViewCell
        let pod = pods[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(pod: pod)

        return cell
    } else if subscribedButton.isSelected {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FollowingCell") as! FollowingTableViewCell
        let user = subscribed[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(user: user)
        return cell
    } else if subscribersButton.isSelected {
        // similar code to create and return cell
    } else {
        fatalError("Unexpected - no button selected") // Fix your code
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

This is a good and proper use of force-casting. There is no need for the `guard` statements. You want this code to crash during development if your cells are not setup correctly. Once setup properly, it can't be wrong at runtime.

Also, the first line of your `numberOfRowsInSection` should be:

```
var count = 0
```

Comment: thank you for the great response. still not showing data, aka I think the last option "else " is showing the empty cell. Is .isSelected the proper term to use here? I have button actions for each button i.e podsButtonIsClicked. Should I call this action instead? (it needs a (sender: ) .

Also how can I select the initial button.

Comment: Personally, I would have an `enum` property that defines the three possible states of the table view. Then update all of your data source/delegate methods to use the enum value instead of checking each button state. Then update your button actions to update the enum property accordingly (as well as reload the table view).

Comment: I was just about to suggest using an enum. It's a bad idea to use the state of a button or other view to control program logic. You should have an enum instance variable that controls the type of cell and source array used to populate your table view, and set that instance variable from your button action(s).

Comment: @rmaddy Ok so I made the enum file and I am setting the values in the button actions. Then in cellForRow I check if case .pods = displayState { } ? Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `if case` here. Either use `if displayState == .pods { ... } else if displayState == ...` or use a `switch` statement on `displayState`.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you! switched it. Still having my problem in my updated question. (There is both a subscribers and a subscribed query) I think , from my research today, that it has to do with running multiple queries that are happening at the same time
?

Comment: You are off on a completely different question now. Don't mess up this question with a new one about some Parse query. Make that a separate question.